# R-cran put image in outer margin

Tags: r, image, plot, cran

I'd like to put 2 logos (.png) each side ot the title of a plot graph in R-cran.
the rasterImage() function dont allow to put images outside the plot region.
Is it powssible to do that with R-cran?

Comment: What do you mean by *"R-cran"*, is it "base R, no external libraries"? It helps if you provide a minimal working (reproducible) example. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: `rasterImage(... ,  xpd=T)` can plot outside the panel limits, if you set the y coords appropriately.

Comment: thank you , the xpd=T works fine to put raster outside the plot region. rasterImage(LogoUdeM , 0, 110, 2, 130,  xpd=T)
rasterImage(LogoLemp , 11.5, 105, 12.5, 125,xpd=T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650), who [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354986/r-cran-put-image-in-outer-margin/54404812#comment95526250_54354986):

> `rasterImage(... , xpd=T)` can plot outside the panel limits, if you set the y coords appropriately.

---

The xpd=T in rasterImage works fine to put my logo outside the plot region.

```
rasterImage(LogoUdeM , 0, 110, 2, 130,      xpd=T)
rasterImage(LogoLemp , 11.5, 105, 12.5, 125,xpd=T)
```

[image]